# Calculate triadic colors with Sass color functions?

Tags: sass, colors

Is there a way to calculate the two other triadic colors from a single color using the Sass's built-in [`sass:color`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color) module?

For example, if I have `#0070f3` as my baseline color, I want to get `#f30071` and `#8200f3` (as found using [Material's color picker tool](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, with `adjust-hue` passing your base color and a rotation  value in degrees.

Triads can vary the rotation, your example gives a second color at `60deg` and a third one at `120deg` (I guess).

An example [here](https://codepen.io/leodeslf/pen/wvoNXpe).

HTML code:

```html
<div class="block base"></div>
<div class="block base60"></div>
<div class="block base120"></div>
```

SASS code:

```
$base-color: #0070f3

.block
  height: 100px
  width: 100px

.base
  background-color: $base-color

.base60
  background-color: adjust-hue($base-color, 60deg)

.base120
  background-color: adjust-hue($base-color, 120deg)
```